# The probability of a radius r given points are uniformly distributed in the unit n-hypersphere

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

A set of points are uniformly i.i.d in the unit n-hypersphere centered at the origin, what is the probability that a point has the radius $r$, i.e what is the probability distribution of $r\in[0,1]$.

For example in 2D this is proportional to the circumference of $r$ i.e $2\pi r$ and in a sphere this is the surface area.

I've read this answer [What's the expected radius of a hypersphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152115/whats-the-expected-radius-of-a-hypersphere?rq=1) but i'm not particularly clear on the distribution they give.

Comment: [The surface area of an $n$-sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Volume_and_surface_area) is $$S_n(r) = \frac{2\pi^{(n+1)/2}}{\Gamma\left((n+1)/2\right)} r^n$$The probability for an uniformly random point within an unit $n$-sphere to be at distance $r$ from origin is proportional to $S_n(r)$. Can you take it from here? If you do, do write your own answer showing it (for others seeking solution to the same problem), please.

Comment: if the CDF is given by the ratio of the volumes, then the PDF is $\frac{r^{n-1}}{n}$?

Comment: @SamPalmer: Note that $$\int_0^1\frac{r^{n-1}}n\,\mathrm dr=\frac1{n^2}\neq1$$ so your proposed PDF is not quire correct. Also note that your question might be better formulated in terms points distributed inside the unit *ball*, since the sphere would usually just be the surface, which makes $r=1$ with probability $1$.